# Add DLL Library reference to project in VSX

Tags: c#, reference, code-generation, vsx

I want to create a new project by code, and add some dll references to my project.

Here is my code

```
System.Type type = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.9.0");
object obj = System.Activator.CreateInstance(type, true);
EnvDTE.DTE dte = (EnvDTE.DTE)obj;
Solution2 sln = (Solution2)dte.Solution;
sln.Create(@"C:\tmp", "TestSolution");
string templatePath = sln.GetProjectTemplate("WindowsApplication.zip", "CSharp");
sln.AddFromTemplate(templatePath, @"C:\tmp\Project", "TestProject", false);
Project proj = sln.Projects.Item(1);
VSProject2 vsproj = (VSProject2)proj.Object;
vsproj.References.Add(@"C:\testfile.dll");
vsproj.Refresh();
sln.SaveAs("TestSolution");
```

But when I open the project and look in "references" there isn't any Testfile.dll added. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need to [save project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/envdte.project.save.aspx):

> `proj.Save();`

before saving solution.

I tried it with `msvs2010`, so I'm not sure that in `msvs2008` it is the same.

Comment: Hey cool! thanks! Do you know if it's possible to remove references from the project?

Comment: @Mathias [`Reference` has `Remove` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vslangproj.reference.remove(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: @Mathias Has it helped?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 sln.Projects[0].References.Add(@"C:\testfile.dll");
```

Comment: When i try the above i get this error message: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'EnvDTE.Projects'